# how to keep tinymce icons bar sticky positioned on top

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

a standard tinymce call:

```
tinymce.init({
...
});
```

there is a lot of setup options inside the above function but I cannot find the way to keep icons bar sticky positioned on top.

This is important because having a long text and need to make a word `bold` I must scroll and scroll... to the top of page, then click `B` and then scroll and scroll down to previous place.

Need to bold another word - scroll and scroll again...

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TinyMCE 5.1 has a sticky toolbar feature that sounds like it would address this issue:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#toolbar_sticky